# Magento 2 theme to build in

Tags: magento2, theme, best-practice

I want to practice with adding themes to a Magento 2 environment, but I don't want to waste time on skinning the shop first. I've been searching on Google for Magento 2 themes, but all I'm able to find are themes that are already developed in Magento 2. That's not what I want. I want a theme that I need to put in Magento 2 myself.

Is there a website that sells themes like this?

Thanks!

Comment: Like a simple theme to get started?

Comment: Yes exactly. Just a theme that needs to be implemented in Magento 2.